# How to change the encoding during CSV parsing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, encoding, csv

I would like to know how can I change the encoding of my CSV file when I import it and parse it. I have this code:

```
csv = CSV.parse(output, :headers => true, :col_sep => ";")
csv.each do |row|
  row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
  insert_data_method(row)
end
```

When I read my file, I get this error:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError in FileImportingController#load_file
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

I read about `row.force_encoding('utf-8')` but it does not work:

```
NoMethodError in FileImportingController#load_file
undefined method `force_encoding' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x2905ad0>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of converting it to a different encoding, would it be possible to add a step of indirection and output separate files? For example, a text file is encoded UTF-8 in some parts but UTF-16LE in others. As long as the headers are identical, output one file to filename_utf8.txt and another to filename_utf16le.txt. This way might make it possible to not force encoding.

Answer (score 16):

I had to read CSV files encoded in ISO-8859-1.
Doing the documented

```
CSV.foreach(filename, encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8', col_sep: ';', headers: true) do |row|
```

threw the exception

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
    from csv.rb:2027:in '=~' 
    from csv.rb:2027:in 'init_separators' 
    from csv.rb:1570:in 'initialize' 
    from csv.rb:1335:in 'new' 
    from csv.rb:1335:in 'open' 
    from csv.rb:1201:in 'foreach'
```

so I ended up reading the file and converting it to UTF-8 while reading, then parsing the string:

```
CSV.parse(File.open(filename, 'r:iso-8859-1:utf-8'){|f| f.read}, col_sep: ';', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
    pp row
end
```

Answer (score 6):

force_encoding is meant to be run on a string, but it looks like you're calling it on a hash. You could say:

```
output.force_encoding('utf-8')
csv = CSV.parse(output, :headers => true, :col_sep => ";")
...
```

Comment: I just tried it. I get this error:

`ArgumentError in FileImportingController#load_file`
`invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`

Comment: try running this instead: Iconv.conv('utf-8//IGNORE','utf-8',output)

Comment: Unfortunately, I get that error:

`Encoding::CompatibilityError in FileImportingController#load_file`
`incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8`

Comment: I assume you don't really care about changing the encode type, your goal is to parse the file. where are you loading your string from ? Maybe there's another approach that can be taken.

Comment: I am loading it from a CSV file. Now it works, I have changed the encoding directly from the file.

Comment: @TheWhite147 you changed the encoding of the file to what? UTF8? Wasn't the file already encoded in UTF8?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I wrote a little [blog post](http://blog.golfymcg.com/csv-importing-encoding-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8/) about what I did, but it's slightly more verbose than what's already been posted. For whatever reason, I couldn't get those solutions to work and this did.

This gist is that I simply replace (or in my case, remove) the invalid/undefined characters in my file then rewrite it. I used this method to convert the files:

```
def convert_to_utf8_encoding(original_file)  
  original_string = original_file.read
  final_string = original_string.encode(invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '') #If you'd rather invalid characters be replaced with something else, do so here.
  final_file = Tempfile.new('import') #No need to save a real File
  final_file.write(final_string)
  final_file.close #Don't forget me
  final_file
end
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: No destination encoding is specified here because encode assumes that you're encoding to your default encoding which for most Rails applications is UTF-8 (I believe)

Comment: Taking the string and using 'encode' to remove the invalid and undefined characters is what worked for me. Perfect, thanks!