# Why is Ruby failing to convert CP-1252 to UTF-8?

Tags: ruby, csv, utf-8, cp1252, ruby-csv

I have a CSV files saved from Excel which is CP-1252/Windows-1252. I tried the following, but it still comes out corrupted. Why?

```
csv_text = File.read(arg[:file], encoding: 'cp1252').encode('utf-8')
# csv_text = File.read(arg[:file], encoding: 'cp1252')
csv = CSV.parse csv_text, :headers => true
  csv.each do |row|
    # create model
    p model
```

The result

```
>rake import:csv["../file.csv"] | grep Brien
... name: "Oâ?TBrien ...
```

However it works in the console

```
> "O\x92Brien".force_encoding("cp1252").encode("utf-8")
=> "O'Brien"
```

I can open the CSV file in Notepad++, `Encoding > Character Sets > Western European > Windows-1252`, see the correct characters, then `Encoding > Convert to UTF-8`. However, there are many files an I want Ruby to handle this.

Similar: [How to change the encoding during CSV parsing in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078974/how-to-change-the-encoding-during-csv-parsing-in-rails#13384964). But this doesn't explain why this is failing.

Ruby 2.4, Reference: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.3/IO.html#method-c-read

Answer (score 2):

Wow, it was caused by the shitty `grep` in DevKit.

```
>rake import:csv["../file.csv"]
... name: "O'Brien ...

>where grep
C:\DevKit2\bin\grep.exe
```

I also did not need the `.encode('utf-8')`.

Let that be a lesson kids. Never take anything for granted. Trust *no one*!

Comment: That `encoding: 'cp1252'` saved my day!